# BIRT report_ repeating the stucture on the basis of group

Tags: birt

With a model like: "student (1)->(*) School, student (1)->(*)  Result (Student,School)"

I need to generate a BIRT report as folows,

---

::::::::::::::::::::::School detail:::::::::::::::::::

School name:***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

Location:***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

School grade:***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

---

Result

### year|result|marks

...

...

---

avg marks     xxx

Summary :  with  conduct has avg % marks

---

I need to repeat the above structure in BIRT report for every school, student has been through. What feature of BIRT report I can/should use to create this report. This is not the simple listing of records and grouping, Th structure I nedd in my report is not tabular and somewhat destributed description of result of one or multiple queries. Where the structure itself has to be repeated for every school.

Comment: And your question is ...?

Answer (score 0):

See Tutorial 1:  Building a simple listing report

Help > Help Contents

You will use the list, with a sub report (probably a table) imbeded in the list, the sub table will limited to just the student who is being reported for each list event.